# Firefox gives wrong title in address bar suggestion

Tags: firefox

*Something* went wrong somewhere, I tried clearing my entire browser data (except profile, since that would loose my bookmarks and extensions) and it's still wrong. Typing "youtube.com" in the address bar gives me a suggestion with the title of some random video on Youtube instead of the front page.

[image: Screenshot illustrating the issue]

(Click image for video.)

How can I fix this? Preferably without loosing my bookmarks and extensions (and extensions settings). I don't mind getting logged out of websites though.

Comment: I went ahead and reworded your question so the problem is clear without looking at the video.

Comment: As for the question: You said you “cleared everything“, but did that include all history? What about bookmarks, any Youtube videos there?

Comment: @DanielB Yes, I cleared all history, and all my bookmarks only point at the base site, not specific pages on the site.

Comment: IN my experience, Firefox indexes the history and bookmarks.  If that url is showing up then you have NOT cleared one or the other.

Comment: I voted for this question to be reopened.  Hopefully others will too.  Feel free to ping me if it gets reopened, and I will write an answer for you as soon as I have time (unless others have time to help you first).